# Alternative to Mono Migration Analyzer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono

I want to analyze an existing .NET-Application about its ability to possibly run on other operating systems than windows. There was a nice tool called "Mono Migration Analyzer" for Mono 2.8, but with Mono 4.2 this way to outdated.

Are there some guides or other tools doing that job? Do you have some handy tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.NET Portability Analyzer` from Microsoft to assess support for the .NET Core which is cross-platform.

Find it here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b

Comment: Is there a version of this for some platform other than Visual Studio?

I'm looking for something similar that is compatible with a Linux/Mono development environment such as Linux MonoDevelop.

Comment: @RobertWmRuedisueli very late reply, but https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport does have a standalone console version now. People might have packaged it into a MonoDevelop plugin.